# Hiding elements in jQuery inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a table with `tr` and `td`. My `td` has a `div` as its child. One `div` has `id="question"` and another has `id="answer"`. I want, while traversing my `td`, the `div` that has `id="answer"` to be hidden. When page loads, only then the question `div` should appear. Here is the structure of the html

```
<td style="display: none;">
    <div style="border-color: #000000;position: relative;float: right;margin-top: 2px;right: 12%;"> </div>
    <div style="border-color: #000000;position: relative;float: right;margin-top: 2px;right:-2%;"> </div>
    <div id="question">
        <img id="faqGrid:0:j_idt77" height="10" width="480" src="/TDAP/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.RC2">
        <br>
        <br>
    <div id="answer">
    <div class="horizontalline"></div>
</td>
```

I did the following. But it hides whole td.

```
$('#faqGrid tr td').each(function(){

    var $cells = $();

   /**
    *Gives you all children as an object array
    * 0: div
    * 1: div
    * 2: div#question
    * 3: img#faqGrid:0:j_idt77 /TDAP/fa...=2.2.RC2
    * 4: br
    * 5: br
    * 6: div#answer
    * 7: div.horizontalline
    */
    var tdChildrenArray = $(this).children();

    var divChildrenArray = $(this).children('div');

    var elementStack;

    $.each(divChildrenArray, function(index, value){

       var $div = value;

       if ($div.id) {

           var $divId = $div.id;

           if ($divId == 'answer') {

              var colNum = $(this).cellIndex;
              $cells = $cells.add($div);

           } //end of if ($divId == 'answer')

       } //end of if ($div.id)

    }); //end of  $.each(object, fn)

    return $(this).pushStack($cells);

}).hide(); //end of $('#faqGrid tr td').each(fn)
```

My idea here is that, the `div`'s that are on the push stack only should hide, but that's not the real output.

Comment: oh that was by mistake, sorry

Comment: Don't use ids. as I see that this structure can be repeated. ID is an unique identifier for the whole document. Instead use a class name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use multiple ID attribute which you will be doing if you have more than one row. Change this to class instead...

```
<div class="question">
    <img id="faqGrid:0:j_idt77" height="10" width="480" src="/TDAP/faces/javax.faces.resource/spacer/dot_clear.gif?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2.RC2">
    <br>
    <br>
<div class="answer">
```

Then you can do this simple JQuery to hide the answer elements...

```
$(".answer").hide();
```

To answer you question directly, you are called the `.hide()` function on your collection of TD elements anyway.

You could move `.hide()` from the very end and put in with this line...

```
if ($divId == 'answer') {

    $div.hide();//hide your answer element
    var colNum = $(this).cellIndex;
    $cells = $cells.add($div);

} //end of if ($divId == 'answer')
```

...but this is way to much code for something so simple

**EDIT**: [A Sample of what you might be trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/9dJUd/)

Comment: @davidethell Eirinn  Thanks. I want to ask, the only reason to choose class here instead of id, is, that id should be unique? Yes you are right this structure is repeated. And in that case all td has id=question, and id=answer. Also is it fine to have all tds have same class name instead of same id? Thanks

Comment: @Basit: Yes, it is perfectly normal for different elements to use the same class name. This makes styling in CSS much easier too. It is very good practice to keep ID value unique. Even if things seem to work OK with the same ID there is a good chance something later down the line wont work properly ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a selector.

Give all answer boxes a class of "answer"

And use:

```
$(".answer").hide();
```

this will hide all of them with the answer class. To show them call the question ID and the answer class:

```
$("#Q1 .answer").show();
```

I'm not very well versed in tables unfortunately, but i hope the answer has some value.

**Edited to reflect comments.**

Comment: your second selector, with the `#Q1`, will that work that way around?

Comment: It should work yes :) if it doesn't they might have to be swapped around. It looks for .answer inside #Q1. This method does require each question to have their own ID... #Q1,#Q2 and so on.

Comment: Yeah I got what you were trying to do, I just thought you had to put the parent first, and the child second... I may be wrong, I have never tried before...

Comment: ...needs to be the other way arround: `$("#Q1 .answer").show();`

Comment: Yeah sorry, parent first then child :)

Answer (score 1):

It is better for element ids to be unique across your document. This isn't absolutely required, but it will make it easier to work with your elements. In your case I would change all your question and answer id attributes to classes instead. Then you can do this to hide all your answers:

```
$('#faqGrid tr td div.answer').hide();
```

Comment: Hmm if give my div class attribute, like `div class="question"`, then how can i check for this attribute. Like i am doing `if ($div.id) `, i can't do `if ($div.class)`. ? thanks

Comment: `$div` is a JQuery element and thus you can do... `$div.attr('class')`